# fastest way to convert opencv cv::Mat to open3d::geometry::Image

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, open3d

I have an image in OpenCV format: `cv::Mat depth_mask` : `CV_32F`, and I want to convert it to [`open3d::geometry::Image`](https://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/cpp_api/classopen3d_1_1geometry_1_1_image.html) in order to construct an Open3D pointcloud from the depth mask.

can you please tell me if there is faster way than looping the pixels and assigning them one by one? thanks.

Comment: did you tried `std::memcpy`?

Comment: Fastest will be passing the ownership of data from mat to image, but not sure if it's possible.

Comment: you can construct a cv::Mat that uses foreign memory instead of its own. whatever OpenCV functions can then write into it. it has to have the correct element type and size, or else those functions will fail (with own-memory Mats, they would resize the Mat to fit the result)